# Python Script Dies After a Few Hours (on Windows)

Tags: python, windows

I have a python script which I'm trying to run as somewhat of a daemon on a Windows system. The code looks something like:

```
import threading
import requests

def do_something():
  while True:
      try:
          response = requests.get(some_url)
          print datetime.now()
      except Exception, e:
          print str(e)
      time.sleep(5)
  return True

threading.Thread(target=do_something).start()
```

However, every three or four hours, the script just stops processing. It doesn't close, just hangs. No errors are reported.

Is there a better way in Python on Windows to run a service like this?

Comment: Why would someone vote down my question without even a constructive comment...?

Comment: I don't know so I've upvoted it to balance things up ;). It may very well be that you are running out of ram, do you close those threads at any point? Can you try running it without the sleep and see whether it will hang too?

Comment: Also you don't seem to handle the case of request.get failing, which may happen if, for example, networking goes down even very briefly.

Comment: I'm hesitant to run it without sleep because it will then be hitting the server with HTTP requests constantly. I do not close the threads, but there should only be one thread launched, correct? It only appears in Task Manager as one python instance and the memory never goes above 30MB and stabilizes at 17MB after each processing instance occurs.

Comment: @puciek I took out all of the try/except clauses for my above example, but I do log errors when the requests fail, and they do sometimes. However, the service logs those errors and keeps trying until it connects again and continues operating without problems until it just freezes.

Comment: It does assuming that this is the script in full, and since you have stubbed almost every bit of it - can't be sure. And since the request.get runs in separate thread, I would assume that the cause for hang happens in the code after you launch the thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62549/discussion-between-tufelkinder-and-puciek).